# Django postgres migration issues when adding fields to existing models

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, migration

I currently have a project in production. When trying to add new fields to existing models I am having issues with migrations which is causing me to worry about data loss.

The errors I'm getting is that it says the fields don't exist when I can clearly see in the latest migrations file it has been added.
I have never had this issue before when adding new fields and then pushing to the remote repository and then pulling it into production where I would then do the migrations.

Comment: Can you share the full error traceback and model in which you added these fields

Comment: Hi Rahul ProgrammingError: column Sale.flag_date does not exist.  The issue is I can see in the migrations file under operations it was added.

Comment: Habe you run `migrate` after each makemigrations?

Comment: Hi i found the problem. i inserted the flag_date row between exisiting fields so for some reason it didnt recognize that it was there.